# Find length of char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, codeblocks

I'm creating a text-based hangman game in Code::Blocks ( C++ Obviously ;) ).

So i've created an array char knownLetters[]; but i'll have no idea how long the word will be, how can i calculate how many char's there will be in the string?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

string GenerateWord() // Generate random word to be used.
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        int wordID = rand() % 21;
        string wordList[20] = {"Dog" ,"Cat","Lion","Ant","Cheetah","Alpaca","Dinosaur","Anteater","Shark","Fish","Worm","Lizard","Bee","Bird","Giraffe","Deer","Crocodile","Wife","Alligator","Yeti"};
        string word = wordList[wordID];
        return word;
    }
void PrintLetters() // Display the word including underscores
{
        string word = "";
        char knownLetters[word];
        for(int pos = 0; pos < word.length(); pos++) {
        if(knownLetters[pos] == word[pos]) cout << word[pos];
        else cout << "_";
}
    cout << "\n";

}
void PrintMan() // Display the Hangman to the User
{
    // To Be completed
}
void PlayerLose() // Check For Player Loss
{
    // To Be completed
}
void PlayerWin() // Check For Player Win
{
    // To Be completed
}

int main()
{
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Look up `std::vector` and forget about C-style arrays until you grasp it.

Comment: `char knownLetters[word];` What exactly are you doing here?

Comment: If you plan on printing a word, you need to surely know the word to print? If this word is a string then its easy to gets its size and therefore you know the size of the array? Also you should use a vector instead of a char array

Comment: MarounMaroun
I am creating a char array with the length of the word provided from the string generated in generateWord();

@Moore91
The word is randomly generated, from a list of words in
generateWord(); So it could be 3 char's, or it could be 6 char's if you know where i'm coming from.

Comment: No. Its still a std::string, use .size() to find its size

Comment: @Mgetz Yeah, question looks similiar, i searched but obviosly not enough, that question answered my question, i can just find the length from sizeof() :) Thanks everyone anyway though, i'll certainly look at your methods also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the random string generated you use the `size` method to find its size

```
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/
```

This can then be used for the size of the array or better yet use a vector and then you do not need to worry about the size

```
void PrintLetters(const std::string& word) // Pass the word in here
{
    const int size = word.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a C char-based string, you can use **strlen**. However, the string must be \0-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a .size() method of std::string

Answer (score 0):

I think Standard Template Libraries (STL) can be of great use to you here.
Specially std::vectors. Vectors does not require the length of string you want to put in. 
You can use ITERATORS to navigate inside a vector.

Answer (score -1):

Can find the length of the generated word through sizeof.

I.E

```
int length = sizeof(word);
```

answer from:
[Finding length of char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150258/finding-length-of-char-array)

Comment: but word is a std::string not a char array. Use the .size() member

Comment: sizeof doesn't get the length of a word. It returns the amount of memory ( in bytes ) that the variable takes up.