# How to find the size of a string inside a function in C?

Tags: c, function, sizeof

Firstly before I explain, here is the code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printSize(char* str);

int main()
{
    char a[100] = "StackOverflow";
    printSize(a);
    return 0;
}

void printSize(char* str)
{
    int n = sizeof(str) / sizeof(char);
    printf("%d" ,n);
}
```

As you can already see, I am trying to get my function to print the value "100" as 100 is the size that I have allocated to my `char` array `a`. However I am getting 8 as my answer. Now I know why I am getting 8 here because it's printing the size of the pointer. So my question is, if I can't use this method to print out the value of "100" then how can I find out the memory allocated to `a` from inside the function?

Thanks

Comment: You can't find it with easy methods. Usually what is done is to add another parameter to the function, `int size`, which tells you the size of the array.

Comment: [Finding the length of a Character Array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4180818/995714)

Comment: So basically there is no way to do it in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the length of a string you use the [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function. To get the size of the *array* you need to pass it as an argument.

When you get the size of a pointer, you get the size of the actual *pointer* and not what it points to. In your case you seem to be on a 64-bit platform where pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes), then dividing that by `sizeof(char)` (which is defined to always be `1`) you get the value `8`.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` for `strlen()`.

Comment: Yeah I know about strlen and the reason why I kept getting 8 as an output, however is there anyway to get this to work without adding a third parameter in my function and also not adding a extra int byte in my allocated memory to store the size?

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 No there's no way. Once an array has decayed to a pointer, all you have is the pointer, and you have lost all semantic information the compiler might have had for the array.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for your help.